# Google App Script returns array over multiple rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, cross-join

## Summary

I'm new to Google Apps Script but I've spent quite a bit of time researching and have come up empty. Basically I'm trying to replicate a cross-join functionality of SQL. I have 2 tables, a calendar table with 12 months, and a customer table with 3 customers. The customer table is populated from a Google form, and will have new customers added going forward.

For my reporting, I need the customer data to be at a monthly grain. Therefore I want to cross-join the customer data with the calendar to create a dataset with 36 rows, where each customer has 12 rows, one per month.

Based on other code I've found on stackoverflow, I've gotten close. My issue now is that my two data sets end up displaying on subsequent rows, which seems like an issue with how I'm handling my arrays. I have also tried using push.apply and .concat with the exact same results.

Any help would be appreciated! Workbook can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fUGShEq59xutuMB6W4OWqOs4x4VT6j4BQvP3hQ24xXo/edit?usp=sharing)

Also, the calendar table isn't strictly necessary - I just come from a SQL background so my first instinct was to make a calendar table and create a cross join. If you can think of a better way to accept a single row of customer data from a Google form and output X rows with consecutive months and years added, let me know!

**Disclaimer:** I know this cross-join method would be better handled in a SQL database, and that Google Sheets isn't designed for this. This is a temporary workaround while a better long-term solution is being designed. The customer dataset will likely be less than 100 customers total for this workaround, and is growing at a rate of approximately 1 customer per week.

## Calendar Table

[image]

## Customer Table

[image]

## Custom Code

```
function crossJoin(tabl1, tabl2, header) {
 var output = [];
  var days = tabl1;
  var customer = tabl2;
  if(header) {output.push([header[0][1], header[0][0]])};
  for(var i = 1, iLen = customer.length; i < iLen; i++) {
//     output.push(days[i]);
    for(var j = 1, jLen = days.length; j < jLen; j++) { 
      output.push(days[j],customer[i]);

    }
  }
  return output;  
}
```

## Current Output

[image]

## Desired Output

[image]

Comment: And why not show what the current output looks like and what you expect it to look like?

Comment: Google Sheets are not designed for this kind of thing. While its possible to write code to simulate SQL joins, these queries are going to be extremely slow when compared to a true relational database. 

For large enough data sets you're likely going to run into time-out issues (app script is bound by a 6-minute execution limit). 

You might want to consider looking into other storage solutions like Cloud SQL.

Comment: Why not use a JDBC connection to a MySQL database?

Comment: @tehhowch added the current and desired outputs. I've also linked to my sheet that demonstrates this.

Comment: @TheMaster I tried both .push.apply and .concat and they both generate the same result as .push

Comment: @DimuDesigns thanks for mentioning this. I've worked with SQL databases for quite a while and that's definitely a preferred method for doing this. However, for this particular use case, this is a temporary workaround while a longer-term solution is being developed by the company. The current methodology I've inherited is copying/pasting lots of Excel rows and duplicating them 12 times and all sorts of funky steps that introduce errors and take forever to complete.

Comment: @DimuDesigns I'm trying to streamline by creating a Google Form for data collection of Customer data. The data needs to be at a monthly grain, so here I'm trying to programmatically duplicate it across 12 months to artificially create that grain. The idea is - input customer data once in the form, get 12 rows of customer data, one per month, in the backend. This solution won't be used for more than 100 customers, so the dataset will stay small.

Comment: @Cooper added a disclaimer to my original post. Basically I've inherited a lengthy and error prone copy/paste/duplicate process in Excel that I'm trying to streamline as a temporary (aka 6 months or less) workaround to make my life easier. Long-term this will be handled using an app and a database. For now, I thought it would be easier to use a Google form for customer data entry, and then an automated process to duplicate that across 12 months to create the dataset I need.

Comment: Have you looked at the syntax of `array#push`?  Each method parameter is added to the end. They are not joined together then added, so you must do that first.

Comment: @tehhowch thanks for clarifying. I guess I don't really understand what array#push actually does. The code from TheMaster gave me an example to work from and I was able to get the desired output. I'll be trying to dive into syntax and uses for array properties further, but thanks for the help on this - it was a bit of an overwhelming intro to Google App Script.

Comment: Use a JavaScript language reference like Mozilla Developer Network ("MDN") to confirm that how you use functions is how they are supposed to be used. For interactions with Google-specific services (e.g. `SpreadsheetApp`) use the Apps Script documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array methods like `concat` to achieve the same result.

#### Code Snippet:

```
function sqlCrossJoin(arr1, arr2) {
  arr1 = arr1 || [['jan', 1], ['feb', 2]];
  arr2 = arr2 || [
    ['Jane Doe', 1983, 'PortLand', 'Oregon'],
    ['John Smith', 1984, 'San Francisco', 'California'],
  ];
  var output = [];
  arr1.forEach(function(month) {
    arr2.forEach(function(customer) {
      output.push(month.concat(customer));
    });
  });
  return output;
/* Expected Output:
[ [ 'jan', 1, 'Jane Doe', 1983, 'PortLand', 'Oregon' ],
  [ 'jan', 1, 'John Smith', 1984, 'San Francisco', 'California' ],
  [ 'feb', 2, 'Jane Doe', 1983, 'PortLand', 'Oregon' ],
  [ 'feb', 2, 'John Smith', 1984, 'San Francisco', 'California' ] ]*/
}
```

#### References:

- [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster for the code sample. I don't fully understand .push and .concat and was not combining them properly - javascript is not my forte. Coming from a SQL background, true code is a bit harder for me to grasp. The .forEach is a nice touch as well, I just have to be careful when using headers. From your example I was able to get my workaround working and it will save me hours of manual labor. Thank you! - Now to dive into more documentation and really try to understand push and all the array properties.