# To merge data similar as a SQL JOIN, dynamically: by functions INDEX and MATCH : google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there maybe a better way to archieve this, **to merge data** similar as a SQL JOIN, **dynamically**?
My idea is doing it by the functions **INDEX** and **MATCH**

But then I got stuck to make it more flexible and dynamic; to retrieve one single row/column from a range - for using in **MATCH** : google spreadsheet???

---

I'm trying to make a dynamic range of a table in google spreadsheet ... depending on the available data.

To merge data similar as a SQL JOIN, dynamically:

By to join several tables, ranges together ...
is to the mix the functions INDEX and MATCH ...
Is there a possibility/function to retrieve a single row/column from a range?

Why?
The function MATCH in google spreadsheet, just allows a range of just a SINGLE row/column.

[image: not dynamic - links]

---

**My solution at this moment is doing it by dynamic - named ranges**

---

Is to define every range apart ...

**Data > Named ranges...**

complete range  | *header*  |  data range | *1st column*
In this case :

- range    : **TBL_ITEM_TYPE!A1:D7** --> *range_ITEM_TYPE*
- header   : **TBL_ITEM_TYPE!A1:D1** --> *header_ITEM_TYPE*
- data : **TBL_ITEM_TYPE!A2:D7** --> *data_ITEM_TYPE*
- 1st column   : **TBL_ITEM_TYPE!A2:A7** --> *1col_ITEM_TYPE*
  [see image]

But it would be easier, if it is possible to extract the necessary data/header/1stcolumn from one defined named range.

In this case from  *range   : TBL_ITEM_TYPE!A1:D7*
[image: different named ranges]

---

**A better solution ... idea**

---

Is putting it in one customized function [in the script editor] so it needs less arguments or just one about the range.

To merge data similar as a SQL JOIN

```
=INDEX( TBL_ITEM_TYPE!A1:D7 , 
MATCH( $B2, TBL_ITEM_TYPE!A1:D1, 0)
MATCH( H$1, TBL_ITEM_TYPE!A1:A7, 0)
)
```

1) working with defined name ranges : dynamic ranges

```
=INDEX( indirect(range_ITEM_TYPE) , 
MATCH( $B2, indirect(header_ITEM_TYPE), 0)
MATCH( H$1, indirect(1col_ITEM_TYPE), 0)
)
```

2) with functions 'fHeader' and 'f1Column', to extract the header (1st row) and first column (index) of the data/table(s)

```
=INDEX( indirect(range_ITEM_TYPE) , 
MATCH( $B2, fHeader(indirect(range_ITEM_TYPE)), 0)
MATCH( H$1, f1Column(indirect(range_ITEM_TYPE)), 0)
)
```

3) one function getINDEX : implemented the (sub)functions 'fHeader' and 'f1Column', to retrieve the desired data

```
=getINDEX( indirect(range_ITEM_TYPE) , ( $B2, 0), (H$1, 0))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking and why the question includes the javascript and google-apps-script tags.

Comment: Related:https://stackoverflow.com/a/53584500